Configurar idioma a español en Laravel 11 no funciona
Estaba viendo la pregunta: Obtener el nombre del día en español de una fecha (carbon laravel)
que trata de imprimir el día de la semana en español.
Si no me equivoco hay que establecer como local el idioma deseado e imprimir el día de la instancia Carbón, en Laravel 11:
now()->format('l');

No me ha funcionado.
Así establecí el idioma:
en "config/app.php", tengo los siguientes valores:
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'es'),
'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'es'),
'faker_locale' => env('APP_FAKER_LOCALE', 'es_ES'),

en el fichero ".env":
APP_LOCALE=es
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=es
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=es_ES

Limpie cache y configuración:
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

En el método de controlador que estoy usando para la prueba he puesto:
app()->setLocale('es');
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('es');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');

dd(now()->format('l'));

Nada, imprime: 'Wednesday'

Notas


Uso un Ubuntu + Apache. Si ejecuto locale -a en la terminal, aparece en la lista es_ES.utf8.
Version PHP Cli y Servidor 8.3.14
Versión de Laravel es 11.36.1


Prueba con $dia = now()->translatedFormat('l');

El entorno no está bien configurado, ya que al parecer tiene como idioma predeterminado el idioma inglés, esto aunque muestra correctamente el idioma usando locale -a.

@Excorpion si uso el código que me comentas si funciona
$dia = now()->translatedFormat('l'); echo $dia; // martes

@Jorgesys ¿a qué te refieres con el entorno? ¿mi SO?
